# Command Bar multiple Customisation

Tags: json-formatting, customization

I am trying to customize a modern page command bar and have found some documentation to hide the new button:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/row-formatting.schema.json",
  "commandBarProps": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "key": "new",
        "hide": true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

So far so good, however I am trying to make multiple customizations and also remove the following:

- `Add shortcut to OneDrive`
- `Pin to quick access`
- `Export to excel`
- `Automate`
- `Integrate`

how can I manage multiple customizations in the JSON code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following JSON should work for you:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/row-formatting.schema.json",
  "commandBarProps": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "key": "new",
        "hide": true
      },
      {
        "key": "addShortcut",
        "hide": true
      },
      {
        "key": "pinToQuickAccess",
        "hide": true
      },
      {
        "key": "exportExcel",
        "hide": true
      },
      {
        "key": "automate",
        "hide": true
      },
      {
        "key": "integrate",
        "hide": true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Step by step instructions here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hGlaofOZIhg

Also command bar customization article here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-commandbar-formatting

**Note** that certain key values may not work for libraries. For example, using `exportExcel` as the key will not hide the action from the command bar in libraries. Instead, you can use the key `export` to achieve the desired effect.

There are different keys available depending on whether you are customizing a list or a library. To explore and discover the appropriate keys for your customization needs, you can use the helpful tool provided here: https://sharepointdashboards.com/PRE/?t71. This tool can assist you in identifying the correct keys to hide specific actions from the command bar.